# Script running before sheet has updates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a database type thing where a sheet can write and compare to another sheet. The write is done with a script but the call back is achieved on the sheet with `QUERY`. And as part of the script I am doing some formatting based on these return values.

The issue I have is if I write to the database spreadsheet and then run the formatting straight afterwards the sheet query has not executed in time. I tried using `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` after the write command but it doesn't help and to be honest I'm not really sure what its supposed to do anyway.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient answer, but you might be able to use Utilities.sleep(1000) to wait for 1 second after executing the first command.